# Remove spaces in " " in List of list of list

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, list

```
results = [[['2020 is the year', '29 year old "Samuel G"', '25 year old "John P Krul"', '40 year old "Trey Nunez S"', '22 year old "Fiona S Paul"', '50 year old "Sean J Beal"']]]
```

I tried with following, but this seems to get rid of middle word in " " in python3.

```
print([re.sub(r'"(\w+)(\s(\w+))*"', '"\\1\\3"', x.lower()) for x in results[0]])
```

My desired output is

```
results = [[['2020 is the year', '29 year old "samuelg"', '25 year old "johnpkrul"', '40 year old "treynunezs"', '22 year old "fionaspaul"', '50 year old "seanjbeal"']]]
```

Remove only between "" and lowercase in "" so that "John P Krul" to "johnpkrul" while keeping everything same.

What needs to be changed to code?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
def f(x): #Takes re.match object as input
    a=x.group() #extractting the match
    return a.replace(' ','').lower() #them to lower and removing spaces

[re.sub(r'\"([^"]*)\"',f,i) for i in results]
```

---

```
['2020 is the year',
 '29 year old "samuelg"',
 '25 year old "johnpkrul"',
 '40 year old "treynunezs"',
 '22 year old "fionaspaul"',
 '50 year old "seanjbeal"']
```

Edit:
For list of list of lists

```
[[[re.sub(r'\"([^"]*)\"',f,i) for i in lst2] for lst2 in lst1] for lst1 in results]
```

Output:

```
[[['2020 is the year',
   '29 year old "samuelg"',
   '25 year old "johnpkrul"',
   '40 year old "treynunezs"',
   '22 year old "fionaspaul"',
   '50 year old "seanjbeal"']]]
```

Comment: This doesn't work for list of list of list. TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: Just use the same logic however you want...I'll edit wait. @ytoyoyo